# Missing ToolBox Item

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm seem to be missing the JSON Encoder and Decoder in my Visual Studio 2013 environment.  I have BizTalk 2013 R2 installed in my development VM and the Visual Studio 2013 Premium install as well.  A colleague of mine DOES have the JSON Encoder/Decoder.  My original install was BizTalk 2013 and then I upgraded to R2 when it was available.  My colleague did a fresh install of R2 - these are the only differences I can tell.

Things I have tried:

- resetting my toolbox, obviously it did not work as I'm posting this question
- adding an item manually to my toolbox and in the BizTalk Pipeline components tab, I do not have a JSON Encoder or Decoder
- colleague added the component to my send pipeline when I reopened the project I am unable to compile -- error of: Component 'JSON encoder' could not be initialized. Pipeline component 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.JsonEncoder' could not be resolved (is an assembly reference missing?)

I've looked for any sort of matching DLL, and the closes one I can find is Microsoft.BizTalk.Components.Utilities.dll.  How can I get the JSON Encoder and Decoder toolbox items?  It's almost if my install of BizTalk isn't actually 2013 R2 even though Help -> About says it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution to this was to do a Repair on my install of BizTalk.  Once I did that, I was able to add the two missing Toolbox components.  Very weird how they weren't available before.